xampp database with latest java versions problem
how to connect to xampp database on latest java versions without having a jre file to put the mysql connecter in its lib?
i searched for how to connect database of a java project to xampp (phpmyadmin) and all videos showed that I have to download mysql connector and put it in the lib of jre in the java folder but as I searched I found out that there are no jre files for latest java versions, so what to do?

There seems to be some confusion in this question, and it must be said this site is not for 'how to' questions. To put you on the right track though, you should confine yourself to finding out how to install MySql server and connect to it locally with Java and possibly remotely too
